# Smooth animations inside of WallpaperService draw()

Tags: android, canvas, wallpaper

I am currently incrementing float variables inside of the `draw()` method to alter the `x` and `y` coordinates of a `Bitmap`, although the results are quite choppy and you can see the jumps as it increments. Should I create a thread for incrementing the coordinates??

My code from the draw method:

```
   x += 2.5;
   y += 2.5;
   c.drawBitmap(image, x, y, p);
  c.drawBitmap(image, x - image.getWidth(), y, null);
  c.drawBitmap(image, x, y - image.getHeight(), null);
  c.drawBitmap(image, x - image.getWidth(), y - image.getHeight(), null);
```

But it seems either the animation is too slow or it is choppy. How do I alter my code so the animation will appear smooth at any "speed"??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what about `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator` ?

Comment: @pskink Have not tried that yet, I will try now and update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I was using Canvas incorrectly. Was setting:

```
Canvas c = null;
```

instead of

```
Canvas c = new Canvas();
```